# How can a clock stop working at 99 o'clock?

Tags: yuru-yuri

[image]

**Yuru Yuri Season 2, Episode 4, 12:16**

It stopped working but at 99 o'clock. If it's just the reflection (image) shouldn't it be 88:88? Even if it is inverted it will be 18:66, 66 min, but it is not inverted and after repair it shows the time as 15:49. So is that a mistake or there is something really funny which I am not able to get?

Comment: 9 x 9 = 81? Apart from that, no clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's rather simple, actually − the electronic controller must have experienced a failure and the memory module ended up with unexpected remaining electrical charge when it started working again, but the clock was not designed to counter this possible error, so it does not reset the memory, which results in impossible time, like in this Russian Elektronika-6 clock:

[image]

You could probably get more technically correct answers at [Electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: yep, it could be set to go back to 0 when it hits 24, but not when it is >24